# How to perform databse testing in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, database, eclipse

I am new in selenium.i am trying for the database testing in selenium webdriver using eclipse.

i have install mysql 6.3 server and configure ojdbc14.jar and mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar in eclipse
please help me for how to perform databse testing?

Comment: Are you positive you want to test a database using Selenium? Or do you want to connect to the database from you Selenium tests for some other reason?

Comment: See also http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/9074/8992

Comment: @Radek i want to connect database in eclipse and want to perform the testing on it

Answer (score 3):

Selenium is used for automating user-browser interaction with the HTML and Javascript on websites.
It does not have any functionality to test databases other than indirectly through web applications and HTML pages.

Per http://www.seleniumhq.org/
*"Selenium automates browsers. That's it! What you do with that power is entirely up to you. Primarily, it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) also be automated as well."*

One option to test database information is to use a programming framework for Selenium that allows access to application database information, usually through an implementation of ORM (Object-relational mapping).  One example is ruby-on-rails with RSpec which could allow you to both check the web page view using the Capybara DSL and also check database information via Active Record.  Be aware however that there are asynchronus and timing issues here.  Recently we stopped doing the database check due to these issues which were causing the dreaded intermittent test failures.

[Update - baed on your links the old selenium 1.0 'RC' version had a way but this is now being phased out and is un-supported.

Comment: i am following http://www.qaonlinetraining.com/performing-datebase-testing-using-selenium/  is it possible in that

Comment: rc is old tech and being phased out. support is poor to non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to test the database, and assuming you're using MySQL, then the most convenient way to do it is to use their testing framework: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/en/.

Skip Selenium, Eclipse, etc., they're not the tools for this job, as Michael already pointed out.

Comment: ok.let me check